# Is official generic System V ABI document from SCO?

Tags: x86, abi

Looking at the [revision history](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/revision.html) from SCO's website, is that true SCO is the one who maintains the ABI standard? If not, who are the people maintaining the standard?

Comment: First of all that link you provide doesn't work. Second of all I wouldn't look to SCO for being an authoritative source for anything for the last 15 years or so. Instead I would point you to [The Open Group](http://www.opengroup.org/) and its [UNIX standards](http://www.opengroup.org/standards/unix).

Comment: I fixed the link.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, the SysV gABI document is still hosted by SCO, and has updates as recent as 2013.  I doubt that it's SCO employees writing the current updates, though; SCO probably just hosts it.  I forget if I found a link to it from the current official revisions of the x86 SysV ABI psABI docs, or only from other sources (like osdev.org).  The links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) are what I think are the current best / official sources, but I'm not personally involved in the ABI maintenance / update group.